# How does protein knockdown allow a phenotype to be observed?

Tags: molecular-biology

I am trying to understand how AID2 technology works.

I came across an article that says "Protein knockdown using the auxin-inducible degron (AID) technology is useful to study protein function in living cells because it induces rapid depletion, which makes it possible to observe an immediate phenotype".

Can someone please explain in simple terms how one could make inferences about the phenotype based on protein depletion via AID2.

Comment: Here's a starting point for some research: "Auxin-Inducible Degron System for Depletion of Proteins in Saccharomyces cerevisiae"  PMID: 31503416 PMCID: PMC6741457 DOI: 10.1002/cpmb.104 One way to study protein function is to see what phenotype you get without that protein. That can be difficult if the protein in question is essential for the cell to grow or survive. This system allows you to grow cells normally, then at a time of your choosing add auxin and trigger the cell's own protein removal system to get rid of the protein of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phenotype](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/phenotype-phenotypes-35/) is defined as the observable physical properties of an organism (organism here includes things like cultured cell(s)).

If you knock out the protein of interest you may observe a change in the function, behaviour etc. of the object you are studying via the methods you are using to look at that system. For example, in terms of proteins you might be looking to see how removing a certain protein affects production of a metabolite to investigate which pathways are being for production of that metabolite.

Comment: Yes, the "phenotype" is just what you observe, no "inference" involved.